# TPC-DS data in Snowflake Cloud warehouse is available only with 10 TB and 100 TB, is it possible to get it with fewer records(10 GB or even lesser)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tpc

By default, Snowflake comes with a 10 TB and 100 TB scale of **TPC-DS** datasets. Is it possible to get the same number of tables with fewer records/less volume(**10 GB or even lesser than that**)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given the 10TB dataset is a "tenth of the size" of the 100TB data set, something had to be removed to get that reduction. In the doc's for TPC-DS it notes 400K item verse 500K item. So when you say "same data with less volume" where do you imagine the reduction is coming from?

Comment: What I mean with the same data is the same number of tables, not exactly the same data. With the same tables and fewer records.

Comment: so they don't offer a smaller table, but if you are wanting a "smaller table" you could decided how to filter out the row you don't want. Are you asking if someone else has done this and shared that data, or are you asking how to take a sample from the data, or are you asking how to even meaningfully reduce the data, or are you asking how to keep that reduced data fresh over time (assuming the data sets change over time)

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the 10 TB database and then remove rows till you have your 10 GB of data.

Cloning docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Answer (score 1):

I did this with a CTAS for the year 2002 data. You should ORDER BY , otherwise the new table won't be well clustered. You will need to look at DATE_DIM to determine the date range, i.e.
SELECT ... FROM  JOIN DATE_DIM ON  ... WHERE DATE_DIM.D_DATE ... ORDER BY D_DATE
(or you can use the surrogate keys for the join, doesn't really matter).
Or you could just create a VIEW with appropriate data ranges.
Both are faster and cheaper than DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TPC-DS official kit (you can download it [here](https://www.tpc.org/TPC_Documents_Current_Versions/download_programs/tools-download-request5.asp?bm_type=TPC-DS&bm_vers=3.2.0&mode=CURRENT-ONLY)) to generate the dataset at the scale factor you want (from 1 GB) and then upload it to your Snowflake account.

To generate the data to fill the tables you must use the dsdgen tool present in the kit.